# How to cast custom type slice to primitive slice in Golang?

Tags: go, slice, custom-type

```
type TCustomIntType int

func aFunc() {
    var fails []TCustomIntType = []TCustomIntType([]int{})
}
```

I got:

`cannot convert []int literal (type []int) to type []TCustomIntType`

How to fix it? Do I have to write a convert func manually?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_with_same_underlying_type

Comment: Thank you for your link @CeriseLimón

Comment: Note that you can't cast _anything_ in Go. Go doesn't do type casting, only type conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to copy it manually with a for loop.